# Why is my parse not allowing me to write permissions to other rows?

Tags: ios, swift, database, xcode, parse-platform

I want to allow all users to be able to write to any row. As when they request to follow someone, they then 'add themselves' to the pendingFollowers row of that user. However, when I try this, in the log I get an error of "[Error]: Object not found.". I have set the security permissions to be write and read for that class, so I believe that it shouldn't be a problem. My code is a bit clunky at the moment but hopefully you can get the idea. I've shown here that the permissions are set correctly (or so I believe).

[image]

```
                    // This does get hit

                    print("#124 got hit")

                    // This says that there are 1 objects

                    print("There are this amount of objects " + String(describing: objects?.count))


                    currentPendingUsers.append(nameOfMostRecent)

                    for i in 0...currentPendingUsers.count-1 {

                        print("#125 got hit")

                        // This shows the other user which this person has requested to follow

                        print(currentPendingUsers[i])
                    }

                    // This tries to add the user to pending followers row - where the error is thrown

                    object.addUniqueObjects(from: currentPendingUsers, forKey: "PendingFollowers")

                    object.saveInBackground()


                }
```

Comment: You need to programmatically modify ACL access for current user(object in your case).

Comment: I did also try that, to no effect. With this code  let acl = PFACL()
        acl.getPublicReadAccess = true
        acl.getPublicWriteAccess = true
        PFACL.setDefault(acl, withAccessForCurrentUser: true)

Comment: assign newly created "acl" to your object which you are trying to modify.
may be like object.ACL=acl.

Comment: I've also tried that, but unfortunately to the same error